# Excel VBA wont save

Tags: excel, vba

When I try to save this document through my macro

I get the error run-time error 1004- You cannot save this workbbook as the same name.

I wish to just overwrite the existing document when I run the macro.

```
Sub sendemail()
    'Save the form with todays date
    Application.Save "doc.xlsm"

    'Create the email
    Dim OutApp As Object
    Dim OutMail As Object
    Dim strbody As String


    Set OutApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set OutMail = OutApp.CreateItem(0)

    strbody = "<HTML><BODY>"
    strbody = strbody & "<A href= ""http://ne-sharepoint.xsxxu.xxcorp.xxx.biz/ASP/SFP/xP/xxx-OPS/Shared%20Documents/00.%20Shift%20Schedule/ShiftRota.xlsm"">Link to Sharepoint</A>"
    strbody = strbody & "</BODY></HTML>"
    On Error Resume Next

    With OutMail
        .To = "[email address]"
        .cc = ""
        .BCC = ""
        .Subject = "New Holiday Request on " & Format(Now(), "dd/mm/yyyy") & " by " & Range("C2") & ""
        .HTMLBody = strbody

        .Send

    End With
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set OutMail = Nothing
    Set OutApp = Nothing
    Debug.Print strbody
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use

```
Application.Save
```

if you want to retain the file name.

Answer (score 0):

```
'Save the form with todays date
Application.Save "doc.xlsm"
```

This suggests you want to save it under a specific name? such as doc20131219.xlsm? If So

```
Application.Save "doc" & Format(Now(),"yyyymmddHhNnSs") & ".xlsm"
```